# Overlay content areas in Bootstrap 3 site when responsive menu is opened

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I overlay the content areas of a Bootstrap 3 site with a semi opaque [50% alpha] overlay when someone opens the nav-stacked menu, only when the site is viewed on a phone [i.e. only for @media (max-width: 767px)]

Is this even possible with CSS or will I have to use some jQuery?

**UPDATE**

Thanks guys - you provided the clues, what I ended up doing was :

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
$("<div class='overlay'></div>").appendTo($(".content, .footer").css("position", "relative"));
})

// and some css

/* navigation overlay */
div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but maybe something like this?

**JS**

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
  $("body").toggleClass("nav-open")
})
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body.nav-open:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
}
```

Comment: for fixed will need bottom:0 and right:0 set also to fill body

Comment: This is a good start & gives me some ideas on where to go with it - but the overlay covers the entire screen, navigation included, the nav should still be visible.

Comment: small error David, your $("body").toggleClass(".nav-open") should be: $("body").toggleClass("nav-open")

Comment: Whoops. Edited my response.