# Content overlay when responsive menu is opened OR closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is a followup question for: [Overlay content areas in Bootstrap 3 site when responsive menu is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989499/overlay-content-areas-in-bootstrap-3-site-when-responsive-menu-is-opened)

I got that working, but the overlay does not disappear when the menu is clicked again or if the window is resized. I'm not sure how to make that happen.

Here is the navbar button before it is clicked:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target=".navbar-collapse">...</button>
```

after it is clicked it stays the same:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target=".navbar-collapse">...</button>
```

once it is collapsed the extra class appears:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">...</button>
```

I have a bit of JS that adds an overlay to the content areas 'darkening' them when the menu is open

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){

    $("<div class='overlay'></div>").appendTo($(".content, .footer").css("position", "relative"));

})
```

How can I update that JS so that when the overlay is removed when the button is clicked a second time [to collapse it] AND/OR if the browser window is resized while the navigation is still open?

**UPDATE**

removing/hiding the overlay on a window re-size I just used some css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {div.overlay {visibility:hidden;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".navbar-toggle").click(function(){
    var overlay = $( '.overlay' );

    if ( overlay.length > 0 ) {

        overlay.remove();
    } else {

        $("<div class='overlay'></div>").appendTo($(".content, .footer").css("position", "relative"));
    }

});
```

This will check to see if the overlay exists and if so remove it, otherwise it will create it. If you wanted to take it one step further you could just hide and show it after first creation which is less work for the browser ( not a ton but still a slightly more optimized solution ) I will leave that up to you to discover how to do =]